# Django: Get all the parent data based on a field in both parent and foreign key model

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, many-to-one

I have these two models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.TextField()
    name = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    created = models.DateTimeField(False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and

```
class PostShared(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='postshared', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    shared_to = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    shared_by = models.TextField(max_length=50)
```

A post can be shared by a user to any number of users. Now given a user's name, I would like to get the Post details of all the Posts that a given user might have created or Posts that were shared to him/her.

I tried

```
Post.objects.filter(postshared__isnull=False,postshared__shared_to='user1',user='user1')
```

But I am only getting the Posts that have been shared to the user and not the Posts created by the user.

Comment: Nooo.... Don't work with `TextField`s.... Imagine that a user changes their username, then the list will no longer work. You should use many-to-many relations here. It also looks rather weird that there is *one* `is_accepted` boolean, since if you want to share something to 10 people, these can individually accept/decline.

Comment: They can individually accept/decline, Yes. And they will not be able to change the username. That is not possible

Comment: Use `ForeignKey`s, `ManyToManyField`s, etc. to specify relations between models (entities).

Comment: the point is that this introduces what is known as *data duplication*. Data duplication is seen as a very severe anti-pattern. Even if users are not allowed to change their username, one can remove their profile (in some/many countries, one has the legal right to do that), and then somebody else can create an account with the same username, now the documents shared with the previous users, all of a sudden are shared with the new one.

Comment: The username creation part handles it so they are unique. There is no possibility for them to be duplicated. Same usernames are not allowed to be created.

Comment: but a user has in many countries the right to remove his data. Removing means *destroying* it completely (as in, you can not even retain a username, gender, date of birth, etc.), the fines can go to 500'000 GBP by the GDPR. Furthermore there are more problems here: if you use a separator you have to enforce a username can not have such separator, furthermore it will blow up database storage quite significantly, and slow down performance of the database (since this is basically a custom JOIN you are making, and nearly none, if any, databases are optimized for that).

Comment: When the username is deleted, every object linked to it will also be deleted. But I do understand the point you are making

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187895/discussion-between-bhargavi-and-willem-van-onsem).